# Alternative to Groups.ReadBasic.All - access Groups without Admin consent

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that uses Azure AD to access Microsoft Graph without Admin Consent.

I would like to introduce the Office 365 Groups capabilities into my app to manage the visibility of my application objects. Basically, I need two things using delegated scopes without Admin Consent:

- The user must be able to see basic information for groups in the tenant
- Check whether or not the current user belongs to a given group

I see two approaches:

1. Wait for `Groups.ReadBasic.All`

   Indeed, `Groups.Read.All` does require Admin Consent so it is not possible to use it right now in our scenario. My question is then, is such a scope is planned for Microsoft Graph?
2. Limit the Group management feature to Admin only.

   I could limit the Group management capabilities to Administrators or wait for Admin Consent but the rest of the application must be still available for non-Admin Consent workflows. Is there a way to achieve this?

   The only way I see this is to have two distinct applications registered in Azure AD: `myApp` and `myApp - Extended Permissions`. However, I do not believe this is the right way to go to have two Azure AD apps for the same logical app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#1 is on the cards, but I cannot give you a concrete ETA right now, but I'm hoping it'll be available soon. That *should* give you what you are after.

On #2, this is possible, and it's a feature we call incremental or dynamic consent. It's only available through the new [v2 authentication endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview). As part of the authorize request you can specify the permission scopes you need, - in subsequent requests you can ask for additional scopes. However in your case, the additional scope you want is a scope that you want the admin to consent on behalf of the organization for. This isn't quite possible yet, but is also coming soon. It might be that #1 and #2 land around the same time ;)

We'll update this thread when #1 and #2 are available.

Comment: @dan-kershaw-msft: So I guess #1 never really made it, right?

Comment: #2 is available now.  #1 we don't have, and is not planned for now.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Is there a way to get a user's SharePoint team sites that are created as a part of Office 365 Groups? Without a way to list the user's groups barring admin access, we're unable to display all the user's content to them since the SharePoint sites don't show up when either listing or searching: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f5d4a66-4713-48db-8513-48fd7d1eb91b/unable-to-list-team-sites-in-sharepoint-using-graph-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment (via search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266699/827437).