# Azure AD - Office365APIs. Check if connected user is global admin without admin consent scopes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal, office365api

I have a mutlitenant Office365 web application that authenticates users with an Authorization code flow (my server does the requests to the APIs) secured by Azure AD on OAUTH/OpenIdConnect.

We use `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect, Version=3.0.0.0` and Azure Active Directory ADAL.NET client with `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=2.19.0.0` following [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant).

In my Azure AD application manifest, I use only scopes **without admin consent**.

However, I would like to know if the currently connected user is an Office 365 Global Admin of the tenant.

I checked the accepted [answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173978/programatically-check-if-a-user-is-a-global-admin/174167). That basically reads the response at `<graphurl>/me/memberOf` 
However, it is not acceptable in my situation. Following [this reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/2dc2921de053bbe25d969fd7d5dee8cdea112ece/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof.md#optional-query-parameters), all the required scopes are "Admin consent" scopes.

I tried different approaches: using the `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser()`, looking in `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` and finally examining carefully the parsed JWT to see if there is an info on the Office365 roles of the connected user. All without success.

Can you provide a way to know the current user administration roles within the Office 365 tenants with an application declared with no admin consent scopes?

Remark:
This question is more or less related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720452/alternative-to-groups-readbasic-all-access-groups-without-admin-consent) but the requirements are less strong: we only want to see if the current user is a Global Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you provide a way to know the current user administration roles within the Office 365 tenants with an application declared with no admin consent scopes?

For multi-tenant application, accessing to directory data requires the admin consent.

But once administrators give the consent for the application, all users within the organization will be allowed to use the application (**no need to consent**).

Add consent url parameter "prompt=admin_consent":

```
    public ActionResult AdminConsentApp()
    {
        string strResource = Request.QueryString["resource"];
        string strRedirectController = Request.QueryString["redirect"];

        string authorizationRequest = String.Format(
            "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&prompt={3}",
                Uri.EscapeDataString(SettingsHelper.ClientId),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(strResource),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(String.Format("{0}/{1}", this.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString(), strRedirectController)),
                Uri.EscapeDataString("admin_consent")
                );

        return new RedirectResult(authorizationRequest);
    }
```

For more details, you can reference the sample project [O365-WebApp-MultiTenant](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant).

Comment: I knew that to have access to roles in the tenant we needed admin consent but I was hoping that "checking whether or not I am an admin" could be possible. Granting admin_consent is not possible for us, the application serves also Office Addin (from Store). We have a "bottom up approach", where basic users can use and try the app without admin consent. We could grant admin_consent but only for additional features, that is why we are waiting dynamic consent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720452/alternative-to-groups-readbasic-all-access-groups-without-admin-consent/36731679#36731679