# Regarding admin consent for Group Permission Scope in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Currently the Azure AD application delegated permissions "Group.Read.All" and "Group.ReadWrite.All" requires admin consent.

Refer: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/release_notes

/////snip from the below URL/////

Group permission scopes

The Microsoft Graph exposes two permission scopes (Group.Read.All and Group.ReadWrite.All) for access to groups APIs. These permission scopes must be consented to by an administrator (which is a change from preview). In the future we plan to add new scopes for groups that can be consented by users.

/////snip end/////

In our application we have requirement for these scope permissions with user consent alone. Please let us know any workaround and ETA for this feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to Groups.ReadBasic.All - access Groups without Admin consent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720452/alternative-to-groups-readbasic-all-access-groups-without-admin-consent)

Answer (score 0):

The release notes are accurate.  We are working on some new user-consentable and hope to have these available shortly.  Will post back when these are available.

Comment: @dan-kershaw-msft , yesterday we have Planner GA. Whether any update on new user-consentable graph api?

Comment: Any updates on user-consentable graph api for groups?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, all Groups permissions in Microsoft Graph still require administrator consent. However, we're currently working on a feature that will allow applications to request access to one or more *specific* groups, and end-users will be able to consent in this case. We don't have an ETA yet for this- but we are actively working on it.

Comment: Any news on this?