# Microsoft Graph API: Scope Prerequisites Exceed Requirements

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

### Will the *scope prerequisites* become **specific** to each API call?

For example, my current problem:

> I want a non-admin user to be able to create an **event on a group calendar** [[Group Post Events](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_events)], but the API call requires the *Group.ReadWrite.All* scope, which means that **only an admin** can create events on a group calendar.

This means that there should be a *MyGroup.Calendar.ReadWrite* scope (or similar). Can we expect a change on this prerequisites?

Anyhow, thanks Microsoft Graph team for the **daily improvements**. This project is exciting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have a user consentable group permission scope in the works. See: [Regarding admin consent for Group Permission Scope in Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206481/regarding-admin-consent-for-group-permission-scope-in-microsoft-graph-api)