# Microsoft Azure AD oauth identify user's role and group (orgunit) which user belong to

Tags: php, azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0, office365

I am doing the oauth2 Azure AD.  I am be able to authenticate user and list all the groups for a domain by using using this api reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog

I am having the issue which i really need some help on:

1) When a user login i am not be able to identify user’s role.  In google only admin/delegate admin have permission to list groups thus we are using this to identify admin.  Unfortunately for Azure AD normal user also can list groups as well.  I want to be able to see if user role is User, User Admin, Password Admin etc
[image]

2) Need a way to get the group (orgunit) which user belong to.  I went through the api link (above) several times but not be able to find something helpful.  i did try to set up a local Active Directory where i setup the orgunit and sync over to Azure AD.  But consistently i see department is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to Groups.ReadBasic.All - access Groups without Admin consent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720452/alternative-to-groups-readbasic-all-access-groups-without-admin-consent)

Answer (score 1):

> > 1) When a user login i am not be able to identify user’s role. In google only admin/delegate admin have permission to list groups thus we are using this to identify admin. Unfortunately for Azure AD normal user also can list groups as well.

The `Group.Read.All` scope require the Administrator Consent. However the administrator could grant the consent for the organization. Then the normal user also could list the groups. Please refer Azure consent framework [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/)

> > 2) Need a way to get the group (orgunit) which user belong to. I went through the api link (above) several times but not be able to find something helpful

You can use rest below to get a user's group and directory role memberships

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/$links/memberOf?api-version
```

Refer [GetUserMemberShips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersMemberships).

Comment: #1 Perhaps my question wasn't clear.  I don't need to read all.   All i need is the logged in user's role.
#2 again for this one i need which orgunit logged in user belong to