# Get all root sites listed in share point Admin center using graph api beta

Tags: sharepoint, graph, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I need all root sites listed in share point Admin center shown in image [image]

For that i am using Graph api like follows,

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Bearer token",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "3116b007-e574-5ad4-aedd-3b35fbf76b61"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

But it gives output as follows,

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sharePoint/sites",
  "value": [
    {
      "createdDateTime": "2017-02-18T13:03:01.263Z",
      "description": "",
      "id": "2422c3a2-3c51-40f1-8483-5454aead43c4,412bb897-c754-460a-962d-db22893a1649",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-04-24T02:16:43Z",
      "name": "",
      "webUrl": "https://mps330124.sharepoint.com",
      "root": {},
      "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "mps330124.sharepoint.com"
      },
      "siteCollectionId": "2422c3a2-3c51-40f1-8483-5454aead43c4",
      "siteId": "412bb897-c754-460a-962d-db22893a1649"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i achieve it Using **graph api beta**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to retrieve a full list of site collections via Microsoft Graph. That functionality is "admin only" in the SharePoint API and has not been made available via Microsoft Graph.

We're working on some changes to the SharePoint Sites API for Microsoft Graph that will be rolled out over the next few weeks to make it possible to search for a list of sites / site collections, but we still don't have plans to make available the ability to enumerate all sites / site collections via Microsoft Graph.

Watch the [Change Log](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/changelog) around the Build 2017 conference (May 10-12) to find our all the details.

Comment: Ryan, would you mind sharing which SharePoint API feature could be used today to retrieve this information? We currently use CSOM, but I wasn't sure if there was a better way that allowed us to use purely OAuth tokens to retrieve this data. It would be great if the Sites API included some mechanism to retrieve this.

Comment: Were there any updates on the best way to retrieve the list of top-level site collections?

Answer (score 13):

Using the asterisk on the site search endpoint seems to work

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

returns

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
"value": [
    {
        "createdDateTime": "2017-09-15T01:11:50Z",
        "description": "Let's capture our thoughts in this subsite blog.",
        "id": "xyz.sharepoint.com,5a58bb09-1fba-41c1-8125-69da264370a0,5e9767b8-95bc-4bd1-aeb0-defabcdefabc",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "0001-01-01T08:00:00Z",
        "name": "internalblogs",
        "webUrl": "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/internalblogs",
        "displayName": "Internal blog"
    },
    {   
        ...
    }]
}
```

Comment: **important notice:** This only works in the v1.0 endpoint, if you use this on the beta endpoint, it will fail. I'm also not sure if this means that this option will be depricated in future releases

Comment: This is great, worked. It seems Klipfolio used this.

Comment: As this is using a search index. This won't give you a real-time view of Site Collections. There are also some scenarios where a Site Collection will not be returned here either. There is a uservoice feature request for this here https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/7404925-please-provide-rest-api-to-fetch-all-the-site-coll

Comment: Also don't forget that, this query won't return all results. By default only 200 results is returned.

Answer (score 1):

There now seems to be a way to get a list of the top level site collections via the following request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?select=siteCollection,webUrl&filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null
```

The following page documents this (update September 19th): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_list

My own test though didn't bear any fruit, because the API returns a `Cannot enumerate sites` error. An alternative approach would be to use the `search` query parameter ([docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/site_search.md) updated September 20th):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=contoso&select=siteCollection,WebUrl&filter=siteCollection/root ne null
```

But this only provides the `siteCollection` for the `root` :/ with a list of all `sites` and their `webUrl` of the other `siteCollection's` (like the default ones `/sites` & `/teams`) but not the actual url/hostname of the `siteCollection` they belong to. Though that could be extracted from the `webUrl` path component.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is not an error.

If you follow the `siteCollectionId` with the URL https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites/2422c3a2-3c51-40f1-8483-5454aead43c4/sites you get a list of the sites in that site collection.

Comment: Hi sorry it was not error. I typed wrongly. I tried URL https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites/2422c3a2-3c51-40f1-8483-5454aead43c4/sites. It will give sub sites  of requested 'Site collection(2422c3a2-3c51-40f1-8483-5454aead43c4/)' only. But i need all root level sites.