# /sites/root/sites request returns 404 error "The Resource Cannot Be Found"

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

If I use the GET statement:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/sites/` then it correctly returns a list of sub sites under my main SharePoint site.  But if I add a new Team Site sub-site to my main site and then run the same command it now returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "604af4de-b2b5-48cf-802b-1952a7d10b42",
            "date": "2017-10-07T16:56:48"
        }
    }
}
```

When I delete the new sub-site the GET statement works again.  I thought it was an issue with my SharePoint site so I reported it to Office 365 SharePoint support. They get the same error. It happens with Graph v1.0 and beta but is not in the Known Issues list.
I am trying to use this to get the Drive Id of a SharePoint library on a sub-sub site but cannot get past this issue on the problem sub-site.  Is there any other way of getting a Drive Id of libraries on the sub-site that Graph at present seems unable to access?

Comment: Are you able to see this listed using `/sites/{siteId}/drives`? (i.e. `/drives` instead of `/sites`)

Comment: When I can retrieve the siteId then, yes, I can use it to get the list of drives using /drives.  But my problem is that in order to get the list of drives I need the siteId in the first place.  My hierarchy of sites is root / 'Companies' / CompanyA (etc).  I am trying to access the driveId of a library in the CompanyA site.  To do that I need the siteId of CompanyA site.  But when I try to get the list of sites in Company that is when I get the issue.

Comment: When you replicate this issue, does it matter what template you pick for the team site? I'll try and replicate this on Monday with my dev tenant so anything you share regarding the repro steps would be helpful.

Comment: I have only tried adding a 'Team Site (Classic Experience)' as I know that is what the sub-sites under 'Companies' all are.  Some are newer than others and I'm guessing that a change was made to them in SharePoint at some point and that beyond that point the /sites doesn't work.  I have some other sites that have older Team Sites on them and they work.  I will now try and couple of other types of site to see what happens.

Comment: Have just tried adding (separately) three other types of sub-site (Bog, Document Center, Publishing Site).  The issue happens with each of them.

Comment: There are two issues at play 1) the error code is wrong 2) the failure is triggered by throttling due to too many resources being utilized by the request. Can anyone who's reproing this let me know how many subsites you have before it fails?

Comment: At the root level I currently have 7 sub-sites.  And the call lists all 7.  When I add one more it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the issue of Graph not being able to return a list of more than 7 sub-sites is still there, I have found a work around to enable me to get the Drive Ids of the Drives on the sub-sites.  By using the /sites: /{sitepath} option (NB the colon) I was able to go directly to the required sub-sites and then get the relevant drive Ids.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to follow up and say we have now made some improvements that should hopefully let these kinds of queries work past 7 subsites. So hopefully this issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (v1.0 only) : use

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*`

as proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/48266699/488666)